# Android ImageView selector does not work

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-selector

This is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_small_down_arrow_v4"   android:state_pressed="true"/>  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_small_up_arrow_v4" android:state_focused="false"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_small_up_arrow_v4" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

This is how I applied it on ImageView:

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/change_city_small_down_ImageView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/changeCityRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/change_city_selector"
   </ImageView>
```

Now, the problem is, when I pressed the ImageView, the according state drawable image does not change. I have tried it on other wigdet, also not work. I can't figure out why, becasue I used to do this the same way, and it works.

I have monitored imageview states when it been clicked.

v.hasFocus() : false , v.isClickable() : true , v.isInTouchMode() :true , v.isEnabled() : true , v.isPressed() : true

---

I made a terrible mistake, the white_small_down_arrow_v4 and white_small_up_arrow_v4 actually pointing the same direction, in other words, they are same picture.

so, probably my mistake will help someone else if they found selector does not work, and first thing to do is to check if the state drawables are the same....

Comment: this is the layout that imageview attached on:
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/flymeal_login_header_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
     <RelativeLayout/>

Comment: Try android:src="@drawable/change_city_selector" instead of android:background="@drawable/change_city_selector" @Qin

Comment: @Indiandroid not work, and i tried various state combination desperately

Answer (score 2):

Try this: use image `android:src="@drawable/change_city_selector"` instead of `android:background="@drawable/change_city_selector"`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/change_city_small_down_ImageView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/changeCityRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/change_city_selector"
</ImageView>
```

Comment: did you mean : android:state_active="true", because i can't find state_activated property. I copied you suggestion, imageview does not change

Comment: Did you change the android:background="@drawable/change_city_selector" to android:src="@drawable/change_city_selector" in ImageView ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableintouchmode="true"` in your ImageView property.

Comment: I tried add focusable and focusableintouchmode = "true", but, not work. and I add onClick = "true". not work. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to set clickable to true in ImageView

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

change you **selection** to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_small_down_arrow_v4"   android:state_pressed="true"/>  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_small_up_arrow_v4" android:state_focused="true"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_small_up_arrow_v4" /> <!-- default -->
  </selector>
```

> both of them should be true

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's checked on Android 4.4.2 and 5.1:

**/drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/item_pressed"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**/layout**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivOpenFile"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_settings_item"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

**/java**

```
ivOpenFile = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivOpenFile);
ivOpenFile.setImageDrawable(VectorDrawableCompat.create(
        getResources(),
        R.drawable.vd_action_files_black,
        null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your selector actually has state_selected instead of state_checked the later will not work

```
your_selector.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_unselected" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

if you have state_checked instead of state_selected, ImageView will never work.